# set columns in table to invisible

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

[image]

The two tables are inside one div (please see code below for an cut out of the code from  bottom table), I would like to make the first column of the bottom div invisible....any ideas? thanks for replies

```
 <table align="center" class="detailstable" style="width:100%">
         <tr> 
                <th style="width:70%;"></th>           
                <th style="text-align:left;">Summary</th>   
                <th style="text-align:right;"></th>        
         </tr>
         <tr>   
                <th style="width:70%;"></th>                
                <td style="text-align:left; width:100px;">Labour</td>
                <th style="text-align:right; width:100px;"><%: this.FormatMoney(LabourTotal)%></th>
         </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: @John....can you be more specific?  You wan to hide the <th style="width:70%;"></th> in the bottom row?

Comment: Just set the border to none?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make it look like its 'merged' with the cell that contains the total value, use CSS 'border-right-style' on the desired cell, for example:

```
<th style="width:70%; border-right-style:none;"></th>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't create the unwanted column, and instead position the second (now two column wide) table using the style. I would probably have removed the width from the second table and replaced it with float:right to make it align to the right...